# log4j prints wrong characters

Tags: java, log4j

Somebody reports me that the program I gave him that uses log4j doesn't correctly print characters. He tells me that "é" gets printed in the file as "Ã©" (for example: "Vidéo" becomes "VidÃ©o").

It's probably some encoding issue, but I like to reproduce problems to prove that it's fixed.
I was unable to find good (and short) documentation on the subject so:

1. What causes this problem (and how does log4j chose the encoding?)?
2. Can it be fixed by simply using "log4j.appender.myappender.encoding=UTF-8" ?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: `Ã` is a smoking gun that you are viewing UTF-8 data as raw characters.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`WriterAppender`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/WriterAppender.html) (which is the base class for `FileAppender` and its variants. Has a [`setEcoding`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/WriterAppender.html#setEncoding%28java.lang.String%29) method. So yes: using `log4j.appender.myappender.encoding=UTF-8` should simply work.

Note, however, that  "Vidéo" becoming  "VidÃ©o" looks like it **is** writing UTF-8, but whatever you use to view the file interprets it as some other encoding (usually that's some ISO-8859-* encoding or one of the ISO-derivatives).

`Ã` is U+00C3 and `©` is U+00A9. They are encoded as 0xC3 and 0xA9 in ISO-8859-1.

`é` is U+00E9 which is encoded as 0xC3 0xA9 in UTF-8.

Comment: And even if you do not set this, it will just write using another encoding. Anything that cannot be encoded will be question marks (?), but that does not seem to be the case here, so maybe the file is still readable if you find out what encoding was used (probably the OS default).

Comment: Of course, UTF-8 is best because it can encode everything. And it is always a good idea to explicitly configure this and not have it vary from installation to installation.

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies. How does LOG4J chose the encoding when none is specified?

Comment: @iDemmel: the same way all other components in Java choose the encoding when it's not specified: they choose the platform default encoding that's dependent on the current locale.

Comment: Notepad++ detects the file as being UTF-8, so it must be his client. Thank you!

Comment: @JoachimSauer what myappender is to be used in log4j.appender.myappender.encoding=UTF-8. Please update. I am also having issues in creating log4j file with UTF8 characters, it still shows junk characters. even i have copied this line to log4j file, but doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 6):

If your user is viewing the log files over SSH, then they need to tell their SSH client to use UTF-8 too.