# Java Log4j encoding UTF-8 with special characters

Tags: java, log4j

My log doesn't support specials characters like é or è. 
I would like to write my log with the encoding UTF-8. 
I use log4j and my configuration file is the next one :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
 <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - 
         %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <RollingRandomAccessFile name="fileAppender" 
    fileName="logs/moulinette.log"
    filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/moulinette-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">

        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>%-4r [%t] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5 MB"/>
        </Policies>
    </RollingRandomAccessFile>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="fileAppender"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [log4j encoding utf8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358668/log4j-encoding-utf8) & [how to change log4j log file to utf8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24426013/876298) & [log4j prints wrong characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7024512/876298)

Comment: Sorry but I can't resolve this problem with the others links

Answer (score 1):

Use it as follow:

```
<PatternLayout charset="UTF-8">
     <pattern>%-4r [%t] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
</PatternLayout>
```

Add charset="UTF-8" in the PatternLayout.
See [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html).